# Fringe Benefits (Lodging) for single member S-Corp

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, s-corporation

I own a single member s-corp. Would having the s-corp pay for my personal rent as a fringe benefit offer an advantage come tax time?

Answer (score 3):

If you use "a room or other separately identifiable space" within your apartment *exclusively* for your business, then you might be able to recoup a *fraction* of your rent for that. Check the rules for home office at the IRS and adopt a consistent and well-documented approach. (I would pay your full rent out of your personal account, and then do an "expense report" for the portion that's legitimately business related, but that's not a unique approach.)

Other than that, I agree with the answer by litteadv - You cannot reduce your tax by the full amount of your rent just by having the S Corp pay, and trying to do so is probably playing with fire.  Generally speaking, don't comingle business and personal expenses like that.

Comment: But that wouldn't be related to the S-Corp paying for it, would it?  That's (potentially) deductible on regular, personal income taxes as well, after all. Or does the S-Corp change that and make it so you can't deduct it the normal way?

Comment: @Joe - Details matter, but this is one scenario: Once you go to S-Corp instead of sole proprietor, you cannot deduct the home office on Sec C (self-employment), you need to deduct on Sch A (itemized deductions) b/c for taxes you're an employee of a corporation now, not self-employeed. On Sch A, it's subject to the 2% rule and most people won't get the deduction. If you can *legally* move it into the corporate expenses, then it's 100% deductible as a business expense again on Form 1120S Sch K. My answer is about if and how much you can legally move to the corporate books. Again, details matter.

Comment: Not "a part", but "a room". You can't deduct your work desk that you exclusively use for work if the rest of the room is used otherwise occasionally.

Comment: @littleadv There is some minimal unit to be sensible, but the rule is explicit that it does not have to be a room: "To qualify under the exclusive use test, you must use a specific area of your home only for your trade or business. The area used for business can be a room or *other separately identifiable space. The space does not need to be marked off by a permanent partition.*" (Emphasis added). Source: IRS Pub 587 (2014) under "Exclusive Use" at https://www.irs.gov/publications/p587/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink1000226294

Comment: Yeah, it can be a garage (not a room) or a den (not partitioned), but not just any "part".

Comment: @littleadv OK - I agree with you that it's not "any part." Didn't think anyone would interpret "part" so atomically, but I updated the language to match the IRS pub more precisely. Hopefully anyone going down this path will *read the IRS publication* and *get professional help as needed.*

Answer (score 2):

None whatsoever, no. Moreover, trying something like that would very likely trigger a full audit.